# Converting amqp_cstring_bytes back to C string

Tags: c, rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-c

The AMQP messaging library for C has a function that takes a C string and converts it into it's own byte format for handling `amqp_cstring_bytes`. Is there an inverse of this function to take it's byte format and convert it back into a C string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(char *) <amqp_bytes_t bytes>.bytes` or more advanced function [like this](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/blob/master/amqp.c#L196) (just replace `emalloc()` which is php-specific with `malloc()` like in code below):

```
char *stringify_bytes(amqp_bytes_t bytes)
{
/* We will need up to 4 chars per byte, plus the terminating 0 */
    char *res = malloc(bytes.len * 4 + 1);
    uint8_t *data = bytes.bytes;
    char *p = res;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < bytes.len; i++) {
        if (data[i] >= 32 && data[i] != 127) {
            *p++ = data[i];
        } else {
            *p++ = '\\';
            *p++ = '0' + (data[i] >> 6);
            *p++ = '0' + (data[i] >> 3 & 0x7);
            *p++ = '0' + (data[i] & 0x7);
        }
    }

    *p = 0;
    return res;
}
```

Also, give a look to [`void amqp_dump(void const *buffer, size_t len);`](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c/blob/master/examples/utils.c#L152) function from rabbitmq-c.

Comment: The `(char *) <amqp_bytes_t bytes>.bytes` actually worked perfectly. Thank you.